# phpunit coverage-unit doesn't generate reports

Tags: phpunit, php-code-coverage

[image]

Hi everybody,
i have some problem with phpunit coverage html component.
I installed correctly components and launch command:

`vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html tests`

Tests works correctly, but no html reports generated. Attached the terminal result.
The classic "Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... done" doesn't appear.

Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The error message reads "No code coverage driver is available". Your PHP environment is missing Xdebug or PCOV.